# Customize Context filename when using Entity Framework Power Tools Reverse Engineering

Tags: entity-framework-4, t4

When I generate the Context using EF Power Tools reverse engineering, it created a class with my DB name in a file with my DB name. I was able to modify the T4 template to use a static name for the Context class name. However, I'd like to use the same static name with the class's filename. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to customize the generated filenames in the current version.

Unless you want to try hacking the [PowerTools source code](https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/PowerTools/), your best bet is probably just to refactor the class filename by pressing F2 after generation.

If you need to refactor a bunch of files, it may be worth it to write a small script that renames the classes, and their filenames, and run it after each EF generation.

Comment: I thought of doing this, but it seems they're trying to phase out this tool.

Answer (score -1):

rename the .tt file that is generating the class filename.

per http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx

It says

*Customize Reverse Engineer Templates - Adds the default reverse engineer T4 templates to your project so you could customize code generation.*

Once this command is run, you should be able to rename the .tt file that is generating that particular class filename.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. This really isn't even close to a complete answer.

Comment: actually depending on what they are doing, the name of the .tt file in a T4 can definitely change the name of the output file. the question specifically says the *class's filename*

Comment: Right, and *that* comment starts helping with being a complete answer.

Comment: I'm using the EF Power Tools Reverse Engineering command, which is a wrapper around the t4 templates.

Comment: and it doesn't allow customization of the t4 after the fact or during? how did you change the other deal then?

Comment: It does provide templates that you can customize, but there's no way to change the generated file name as far as I can tell.

Comment: so if you use the reverse engineer templates, and change the name of the .tt file, does that work?

Comment: No. The filename of the t4 template is Context.tt. The file that it generates is <DBName>Context.cs. I'm guessing EF Power Tools Reverse Engineering command has a pointer to Context.tt.